# Sys.glob expansion

Tags: r, filepath

I am trying to use Sys.glob to open a file called `"apcp_sfc_latlon_subset_19940101_20071231.nc".`  The following command works:

```
> Sys.glob(file.path("data/train", "apcp*"))
[1] "data/train/apcp_sfc_latlon_subset_19940101_20071231.nc"
```

But this command doesn't return anything.  I'm don't know why it doesn't work.

```
> Sys.glob(file.path("data/train", "apcp", "*"))
character(0)
```

I want the "apcp" bit as it's own argument because I will be passing a variable instead of a hard coded string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file.path("data/train", "apcp", "*")` returns `"data/train/apcp/*"` whereas `file.path("data/train", "apcp*")` returns  `"data/train/apcp*"`.

Thus in the first case you are looking for files in the subdirectoy `apcp`, and in the (working) case you are looking for files which begin `apcp` within the `data\train` directory.

If you want to be able to pass the `apcp` component as a argument, using `paste0` will work

```
starting <- "apcp"

file.path("data/train", paste0(starting, '*', collapse =''))

# "data/train/apcp*"
```