# Connection problem FTP using RCurl in R - specific folder

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

When I first start R Studio I cannot get the following code to run.

```
library ("RCurl")

userpwd <- "User:Passwd"
tsfrFilename <- "/Path/*.his"    ### there is only one .his file in this pathway ###
ouptFilename <- "output.csv"

url <- "ftp://12.34.56.78/Path/*.his" 
data <- getURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd)
```

Returns this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : RETR response: 550
```

However, after specifying the specific path and file name (as per below) it works a charm.
But, when I subsequently use the original code above, I am able to connect no worries and transfer the file.

```
userpwd <- "User:Passwd"
tsfrFilename <- "/Path/next/next/name.his"
ouptFilename <- "output.csv"

url <- "ftp://12.34.56.78/Path/next/next/name.his" 
data <- getURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd)
```

The original code without specified pathway/name works until I end the R session, then same problem upon restart.

Any ideas why this is happening? 
I cannot specify the specific folder or file name as it is overwritten every 30 minutes and assigned into folders for each year/month, thus I need the *.his to work straight away.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using 'Sys.glob expansion' e.g. `url <- Sys.glob(file.path("ftp://12.34.56.78/Path/next/next", "*.his"))` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938916/sys-glob-expansion)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried that but received the following error:

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to web-prdproxy-usr.dmz port 1080: Timed out

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? From the nature of the error it seems that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.
I had to create a dynamic IP address using the date format as shown below.

```
# Get the date parts we need
Year <-format(Sys.Date(), format="%Y")
Month <- format(Sys.Date(), format="%B")
MM <- format(Sys.Date(), format="%m")

# Create the file string and read
emupark <- glue::glue("ftp://user:passwd@99.99.99.99/path/path/{Year}/{Month}/site}{Year}-{MM}.csv")
sitename<- read.csv(sitename, header = FALSE)
```